# How to access included data after deploying exe with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller to create an .exe file.
I included some files (program icon and loading gif) with:

```
a = Analysis(...,
             datas=[
                 ('ui/icon.ico', 'ui'),   # Include icon.ico in the ui directory
                 ('ui/loading.gif', 'ui'),  # Include loading.gif in the ui directory
             ],
             ...)
```

But when i run the .exe file, it looks like images were not found.
In the python code, i access them using the path in the project structure (i.e. 'ui/icon.ico' and 'ui/loading.gif').
It looks like the internal structure of pyqt executable is different; but i did not find any specific documentation on how to handle this situation.

Comment: The answer to this question has already been given  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/18072035)